# recursive object mapper type in typescript

Tags: typescript

I am creating an object mapper in typescript that is typesafe.

I can get this working at one level deep with [this playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/KYOwrgtgBAKgTgQxAZwGYHs4WHAggYwBcBLdFKAbygFgAoKKAEWABthDgoBeKAcgBNW7YLwA0dAL506hAJ4AHTvCRpM2OAFkE8gDwBlAHzdKNelADaABSjEQUANbBZ6VFD0BdAPwAuN1fdQwAAeHCD8yFDoAEYAVsBEdAwMnlAAFKnIvnoAlNxGSLK5AD6wiCgYWDgEJGTIiVBZ-gDcki20dLYccKgI+JwAcgjYJvUVoEPAPlDIhHC2AOZtDMhgcCATUzNzIIuS0rRyilCWOMhkxlT4q3CghIPYvvfAolDyNwBupGDIT5lQT+YAlJ2rR8LVCK9TmRlOU1DgAIy+GGqSqabQ6E5wM4gIw8Cj1K5wG4gO4TJFlFHqaqkFAAOmYbA4exBYJQEMUWOhFIq6gATOSVDycFpdJjsbjKATrrcnr4MrkuEZkLTCcTSdhaWN1sMANR8fV65WqmUTWkrNYTZlAA) and this code

```js
enum TransformerActions { 
  Delete = 'delete',
}

type TransformerMap<S> = { 
  [P in keyof S]?: S[P] extends object
    ? ((s: S) => any) | TransformerActions
  : S[P];
};

interface Name { 
  forename?: string;
  surname?: string;
}

type Person = { currentName: Name, previousNames: Name[] }

const personTransformer1: TransformerMap<Person> = {
  currentName: TransformerActions.Delete
}

const personTransformer2: TransformerMap<Person> = {
  currentName: (s) => s.currentName.forename + ' ' + s.currentName.surname
}
```

But if I wanted to make this a recursive type so each nested key could have transformations, I can't get the syntax,  have tried this:

```js
type TransformerMap<S> = { 
  [P in keyof S]?: S[P] extends object
    ? TransformerMap<S[P]>
  : S[P] | ((s: S) => any) | TransformerActions;
};
```

But that does not work.

How can I created a recursive type this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood properly, what about something like this?

```js
enum TransformerActions {
  Delete = 'delete',
}

type TransformerFunc<T> = (src: T) => Partial<T>

type TransformerMap<S> = {
  [P in keyof S]?: S[P] | TransformerFunc<S[P]> | TransformerActions | TransformerMap<S[P]>;
};

interface Name {
  forename?: string;
  surname?: string;
}

type Person = { currentName: Name, previousNames: Name[], child: Person }

const personTransformer1: TransformerMap<Person> = {
  currentName: TransformerActions.Delete
}

const personTransformer2: TransformerMap<Person> = {
  currentName: {
    forename: TransformerActions.Delete
  },
  child: {
    currentName: (child) => {
      return {
        forename: `${child.forename?.toUpperCase()} ${child.surname?.toUpperCase}`,
        surname: TransformerActions.Delete
      }
    },
    child: TransformerActions.Delete
  }
}
```

Check out the [playground example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=3.9.0-dev.20200417#code/KYOwrgtgBAKgTgQxAZwGYHs4WHAggYwBcBLdFKAbwFgAoKKAEWABthDgoBeKAcgBMWbYDwA0tAL61ahAJ4AHDvCRpM2OADEwIfAB4YAPi5QAFMjj4AXLACUXQwAUEcEgmZ79UmrIWxEKDFg4ALIIcjoAyobc1HRQANr2UMQgUADWwDLoqFDhALoA-FbhCblQAD6+ygFqmtoRJYYVSv6qOAQkZMjllS2BcCFhxfa5+gDcEuM0tMnscKgI+BwAcgjYlLT0AaCrwIVQyIRwyQDmk-TIYHAgO3sHRyCnEp7eHPY4yGRGFFD4l3CghBW2CsQOAIigcn+ADdSGBkKDkCCdnFcuD8AALYjMPhWN5wD4pSRTGj4TqECHvMjNFR9ACMVmp1WCoR0eIJUXWsV+cH+IEBOwZfhpanapBQADomKx2E9iaSUOSFPiqUKmXAAEyCqqtfostlkDkxejc3n84Gc+ibTDbc2MnWizqSwQy2LiMRczHYqxGy0mgGgqzGDFYvi2TiGH2WqD-QiXFKRqNQLbXc0AAwAJBRg9jxcmbuLCOgAKpyJUAYQQyGAxms4igmezfHFFyu+cLJfLleA4lT7sTlpbKeAWt6IqIYuQTulwA2iaJUbds+NnpxPWFbXHjqlQlnRPEQA).